# Parse error on server, works on localhost

Tags: php

I got a few lines of code that run well on my localhost with PHP Version 5.4.19 but doesn't seem to work on a server that runs 5.3.3. On my server I get the following error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ',' or ';' in
>   /var/www/html/newpage.php on line 147

The code that seems to be giving the error is:

```
    146.    <a href=faq.php?id=<?php echo $systemId ?> class="menuitem">FAQ</a>
    147.    <a href="<?php echo getLink($systemId,'map1')['link'];?>" class="menuitem">Test</a>
    148.    <a href="<?php echo getLink($systemId,'map2')['link'];?>" class="menuitem">Test1</a>
    149.    <a href="<?php echo getLink($systemId,'map3')['link'];?>" class="menuitem">Test2</a>
    150.    <a href="<?php echo getLink($systemId,'list')['link'];?>" class="menuitem">Test3</a>
    151.    <a href="<?php echo getLink($systemId,'map4')['link'];?>" class="menuitem">Test4</a>
    152.    <a href="index.php" class="menuitem">Frontpage</a>
```

The function called in the above code (getLink) looks like this:

```
function getLink($id, $category){
    $category = mysql_real_escape_string($category);
    $id = mysql_real_escape_string($id);
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `links` WHERE `category` = '$category' AND `text_id` = '$id'");
    return mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
}
```

The function getLink should work well and the database is populated. I've tried to do some var_dump() on getLink but the Parse error seem to override that code?

Anyone got any idea where the error might be?

Comment: Looks like your server is running an earlier version of PHP that doesn't support array dereferencing.... when will people learn to develop in an environment that matches their production environment?

Comment: I figured that was where the problem was. Unfortunately I didn't set up the server so I had to change up the code a bit. Care to explain how I can fix my current array syntax error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot directly use `<?php echo getLink($systemId,'map1')['link'];?>` in PHP < 5.4.

You must do something like that, or upgrade your server's PHP version :

```
<?php $l = getLink($systemId,'map1'); echo $l['link']; ?>
```

Comment: Thank you for providing an answer. I realize what an idiot I am now.

Answer (score 0):

You need `PHP 5.4` or higher

```
Function array dereferencing has been added, e.g. foo()[0].
```